# Finding missing number in an unordered list

Tags: java

I wrote a sample code below to find missing number in an unordered list. e.g {5,2,3} should return {1,4}. My question is, is the use of HashMap for quick look correct? The range is 1 and max number from the input list.

```
public List<Integer> findMissing(List<Integer> numbers) {
        int max = 0;
        List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

        for(Integer num : numbers) {
          if(num > max) 
              max=num;
          map.put(num,num);   
        }  

        int missingCount=max-numbers.size();

        for(int i=1;i<=max;i++) {
               if(missingCount == 0) break;

               if(!map.containsKey(i)) {
                   result.add(i);
                   missingCount--;
               }

        }
        return result;
}
```

Comment: Define _missing_. What about 0? What about 6? What about 24123123? Is it a range?

Comment: Do you know the range of the list?

Comment: In your code, if the first number is 0, all the rest is broken..

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming from the code that the missing numbers are the numbers in `1..max` that weren't found in `numbers`.*

The code will work, but it can be improved: `HashSet` can be used instead of `HashMap` when you just need to maintain a set of items without values associated to them. Then you do `set.add(num)`, but you can just construct it with `new HashSet<>(numbers)` instead of adding items one by one. Then use `set.contains(i)` to check for numbers presence in the set.

Comment: Thanks. This helps. I totally forgot about HashSets. :)

Answer (score 0):

Put the integers into a `TreeSet`. `Set.contains()` lets you efficiently check whether or not it contains a given number, and `SortedSet.last()` lets you efficiently determine its maximum element. Then iterate over your range with `IntStream.rangeClosed()`, filter out every element contained in your set, and collect what's left into a new set to return to the caller.

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toCollection;
import static java.util.stream.IntStream.rangeClosed;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.SortedSet;
import java.util.TreeSet;

Set<Integer> missing(Collection<Integer> collection) {
    SortedSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(collection);
    return rangeClosed(1, set.last()).boxed()
                                     .filter(i -> !set.contains(i))
                                     .collect(toCollection(TreeSet::new));
}
```

I made it more general by accepting a `Collection` instead of a `List` because `List` implies order, which you said was unimportant. And I return a `Set` to indicate that there won't be any repeat elements, which makes sense in this context because a number can't be missing more than once.